# $_POST to 2 pages

Tags: php, javascript, post

I have a page with 2 frames. In the top frame is a form called invoice.php. In it you type in an invoice number and then post it. I am wanting this post to be sent to 2 pages that will open in both the top and bottom frames. The top page is called invoicelab.php and the bottom is called invoice2.php. The information that I am posting is called workorder. The form page looks like this - ---





Enter workorder number

What is the best way to pass this information onto both invoice2.php and invoicelab.php. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to change the form's target value, instead of the submit button use simple button, and use a function somewhat like this:

```
function submitForms()
{
    myForm.target = "frame1";
    myForm.submit();
    myForm.target = "frame2";
    myForm.submit();
}
```